# OpenGL Shader Storage Buffer / memoryBarrierBuffer

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I currently created two SSBO's to handle some lights because the VS-FS `in` `out` interface can't handle a lot of lights (Im using forward shading).
For the first one I only pass the values to the shader (basically a read only one) [cpp]:

```
struct GLightProperties
{
    unsigned int numLights;
    LightProperties properties[];
};

...

glp = (GLightProperties*)malloc(sizeof(GLightProperties) + sizeof(LightProperties) * lastSize);

...

glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(GLightProperties) + sizeof(LightProperties) * lastSize, glp, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, ssbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

Shader file [GLSL]:

```
layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer Lights
{
    uint numLights;
    LightProperties properties[];
}lights;
```

So this first SSBO turns out to work fine. However, in the other one, which purpose is VS-FS interface, has some issues:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo2);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 4 * 3 * lastSize, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

GLSL:

```
struct TangentProperties
{
    vec4 TangentLightPos;
    vec4 TangentViewPos;
    vec4 TangentFragPos;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer TangentSpace
{
    TangentProperties tangentProperties[];
}tspace;
```

So here you notice I pass `nullptr` to the `glBufferData` because the vs will write in the buffer and the fs will read its contents.
Like so in the VS Stage:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lights.numLights; i++)
{
    tspace.tangentProperties[index].TangentLightPos.xyz = TBN * lights.properties[index].lightPosition.xyz;
    tspace.tangentProperties[index].TangentViewPos.xyz  = TBN * camPos;
    tspace.tangentProperties[index].TangentFragPos.xyz  = TBN * vec3(worldPosition);
    memoryBarrierBuffer();
}
```

After this the FS reads the values, which turn out to be just garbage. Am I doing something wrong with memory barriers?

The output turns out this way:
[image: Pixels bugging]

Comment: Never use the `memoryBarrierBuffer()` myself, but according to the documentation, it says that the barrier ensures that all changes performed before the memory barrier will be visible in subsequent stages, meaning it wont have the effect for the current stage (if I understood correctly). Since you have it in a loop, I guess you expect it to sync the threads for the next iteration? Doc: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/memoryBarrierBuffer.xhtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, let's get the obvious bug out of the way:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < lights.numLights; i++)
> {
>     tspace.tangentProperties[index].TangentLightPos.xyz = TBN * lights.properties[index].lightPosition.xyz;
>     tspace.tangentProperties[index].TangentViewPos.xyz  = TBN * camPos;
>     tspace.tangentProperties[index].TangentFragPos.xyz  = TBN * vec3(worldPosition);
>     memoryBarrierBuffer();
> }
> ```

`index` never changes in this loop, so you're only writing a single light, and you're only writing the *last* lights' values. All other lights will have garbage/undefined values.

So you probably meant `i` rather than `index`.

But that's only the beginning of the problem. See, if you make that change, you get this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lights.numLights; i++)
{
    tspace.tangentProperties[i].TangentLightPos.xyz = TBN * lights.properties[i].lightPosition.xyz;
    tspace.tangentProperties[i].TangentViewPos.xyz  = TBN * camPos;
    tspace.tangentProperties[i].TangentFragPos.xyz  = TBN * vec3(worldPosition);
}
memoryBarrierBuffer();
```

Note that the barrier is outside the loop.

That creates a new problem. This code will have every vertex shader invocation writing to the *same memory buffer*. SSBOs, after all, are not VS *output* variables. Output variables are stored as part of a vertex. The rasterizer then interpolates this vertex data across the primitive as it rasterizes it, which provides [the input values](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment) for the FS. So one VS cannot stomp on the output variables of another VS.

That doesn't happen with SSBOs. Every VS is acting on the *same* SSBO memory. So if they write to the same indices of the same array, they're writing to the same memory address. Which is a race condition (since there can be no synchronization between sibling invocations) and therefore undefined behavior.

So, the *only way* what you're trying to do could possibly work is if your buffer has `numLights` entries for each vertex *in the entire scene*.

This is a fundamentally unreasonable amount of space. Even if you could get it down to just the number of vertices in a particular draw call (which is doable, but I'm not going to say how), you would still be behind in performance. Every FS invocation will have to perform reads of 144 bytes of data *for each light* (3 table entries, one for each vertex of the triangle), linearly interpolate those values, and then do lighting computations.

It would be faster for you to just pass the TBN matrix as a VS output and do the matrix multiplies in the FS. Yes, that's a lot of matrix multiplies, but GPUs are really fast at matrix multiplies, and are *really slow* at reading memory.

Also, reconsider whether you *need* the tangent-space fragment position. Generally speaking, you never do.